# Filtering data sets with 1e6 elements on periodic values

Tags: matlab, dataset, filtering

A data set can be approximated by the following :

```
total_elements = 1e6;
maximum_value = 1e13;
mySet = randperm(maximum_value,total_elements);
```

or one million unique random values in sequential order from low to high with values in the range 1 to 1e13.

Only values in the range `N-2000:1:N+2000`, where `N = 7000:7000:1e13`, are actually useful.  Is there a fast and memory efficient way of producing a matrix  listing of all the useful events in MatLab?  For loops are an obvious approach but are slow.  The size of the arrays means that approaches that generate larger arrays as part of the process tend to fail due to lack of memory.

Comment: Another reason that we shouldn't your code is that you're overriding the `set` function. Also, look at the help for `randperm`. Don't you want `randperm(maximum_value,total_elements)`?

Comment: @horchler I wish I could give that +2! Ross, I have updated the question to prevent distraction from the actual goal. I hope that is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have this:

total_elements = 1e6;
maximum_value = 1e13;
mySet = randperm(maximum_value,total_elements);

And you want values that are within range of positive multiples of N, you can do this:

```
myRange = 2000;
N = 7000;

m = mod(mySet,7000);
idx = (m < myRange | m > N-myRange) & mySet > myRange;
mySet = mySet(idx);
```

This should be fairly efficient and not consume excessive amounts of memory, on my pc it runs in well under a second.

Do pay attention to the comparison with `m`, it may be off by 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your question appears to be how to efficiently extract subsets N-2000:N+2000 where N=7000:7000:1e13 from a 1e13-element array.

One possibility would be to reshape your data array into a 2D array with the right dimensions so that the "useful" elements all lie in the same rows, and then delete the rows you don't want:

```
N1=100; %2000 in your version
N2=800; %7000 in your version
N3=1e4; %1e13/N2 in your version

array_size = N2*N3;
data = randperm(array_size);

tic
datar=reshape(data,N2,N3);
datar(N1+1:N2-N1-1,:)=[]; %delete unwanted elements
%datar(1:N1)=[];  %according to your specification of the problem, these elements are also not wanted
toc
```

I'm not sure how beneficial this would be for performance with a very large array: testing it on a fairly humble PC, it seems a bit quicker than using a loop for arrays with 1e4 elements.  Reshaping the array is a small fraction of the execution time.

Comment: First of all, I think it solves a slightly different problem than asked. Your solution seems to filter out records based on their location rather than their value. Furthermore it seems to be slower than my solution, though I cannot easily see where to improve. Perhaps avoid using `=[]` to delete as it is usually slower than the alternative of specifying what you want `datar=datar(idx,:)`.